# How fix E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2)?

Tags: apt, dpkg, error-handling

When I'm trying to use `apt-get install or upgrade` I get that message!
I tried this command sudo `dpkg -C` and got this results:

```
The following packages are missing the list control file in the
database, they need to be reinstalled:
 liba52-0.7.4         library for decoding ATSC A/52 streams
dpkg: error: unable to check existence of `/var/lib/dpkg/info/network-manager-vpnc-gnome.list': Input/output error
```

This is the results of this command: `dmesg`

```
[ 3982.201148] ata1.00: failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED
[ 3982.201157] ata1.00: cmd 60/10:a0:00:6b:c5/00:00:18:00:00/40 tag 20 ncq 8192 in
         res 41/40:00:0a:6b:c5/00:00:18:00:00/40 Emask 0x409 (media error) <F>
[ 3982.201162] ata1.00: status: { DRDY ERR }
[ 3982.201165] ata1.00: error: { UNC }
[ 3982.205431] ata1.00: configured for UDMA/133
[ 3982.205450] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Unhandled sense code
[ 3982.205455] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda]  
[ 3982.205458] Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[ 3982.205461] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda]  
[ 3982.205464] Sense Key : Medium Error [current] [descriptor]
[ 3982.205469] Descriptor sense data with sense descriptors (in hex):
[ 3982.205472]         72 03 11 04 00 00 00 0c 00 0a 80 00 00 00 00 00 
[ 3982.205485]         18 c5 6b 0a 
[ 3982.205492] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda]  
[ 3982.205495] Add. Sense: Unrecovered read error - auto reallocate failed
[ 3982.205499] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] CDB: 
[ 3982.205502] Read(10): 28 00 18 c5 6b 00 00 00 10 00
[ 3982.205514] end_request: I/O error, dev sda, sector 415591178
[ 3982.205546] ata1: EH complete
[ 3982.205596] XFS (sda6): metadata I/O error: block 0x181300 ("xfs_trans_read_buf_map") error 5 numblks 16
[ 3982.205609] XFS (sda6): xfs_imap_to_bp: xfs_trans_read_buf() returned error 5.
[ 3984.800724] ata1.00: exception Emask 0x0 SAct 0x800000 SErr 0x0 action 0x0
[ 3984.800733] ata1.00: irq_stat 0x40000008
[ 3984.800739] ata1.00: failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED
[ 3984.800749] ata1.00: cmd 60/10:b8:00:6b:c5/00:00:18:00:00/40 tag 23 ncq 8192 in
         res 41/40:00:0a:6b:c5/00:00:18:00:00/40 Emask 0x409 (media error) <F>
[ 3984.800753] ata1.00: status: { DRDY ERR }
[ 3984.800757] ata1.00: error: { UNC }
[ 3984.803857] ata1.00: configured for UDMA/133
[ 3984.803882] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Unhandled sense code
[ 3984.803886] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda]  
[ 3984.803890] Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[ 3984.803893] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda]  
[ 3984.803896] Sense Key : Medium Error [current] [descriptor]
[ 3984.803901] Descriptor sense data with sense descriptors (in hex):
[ 3984.803904]         72 03 11 04 00 00 00 0c 00 0a 80 00 00 00 00 00 
[ 3984.803917]         18 c5 6b 0a 
[ 3984.803924] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda]  
[ 3984.803927] Add. Sense: Unrecovered read error - auto reallocate failed
[ 3984.803931] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] CDB: 
[ 3984.803934] Read(10): 28 00 18 c5 6b 00 00 00 10 00
[ 3984.803945] end_request: I/O error, dev sda, sector 415591178
[ 3984.803973] ata1: EH complete
[ 3984.804040] XFS (sda6): metadata I/O error: block 0x181300 ("xfs_trans_read_buf_map") error 5 numblks 16
[ 3984.804058] XFS (sda6): xfs_imap_to_bp: xfs_trans_read_buf() returned error 5.
[ 3987.434030] ata1.00: exception Emask 0x0 SAct 0x1000000 SErr 0x0 action 0x0
[ 3987.434038] ata1.00: irq_stat 0x40000008
[ 3987.434045] ata1.00: failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED
[ 3987.434055] ata1.00: cmd 60/10:c0:00:6b:c5/00:00:18:00:00/40 tag 24 ncq 8192 in
         res 41/40:00:0a:6b:c5/00:00:18:00:00/40 Emask 0x409 (media error) <F>
[ 3987.434059] ata1.00: status: { DRDY ERR }
[ 3987.434063] ata1.00: error: { UNC }
[ 3987.436514] ata1.00: configured for UDMA/133
[ 3987.436532] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Unhandled sense code
[ 3987.436536] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda]  
[ 3987.436539] Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[ 3987.436543] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda]  
[ 3987.436546] Sense Key : Medium Error [current] [descriptor]
[ 3987.436551] Descriptor sense data with sense descriptors (in hex):
[ 3987.436553]         72 03 11 04 00 00 00 0c 00 0a 80 00 00 00 00 00 
[ 3987.436567]         18 c5 6b 0a 
[ 3987.436573] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda]  
[ 3987.436582] Add. Sense: Unrecovered read error - auto reallocate failed
[ 3987.436586] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] CDB: 
[ 3987.436588] Read(10): 28 00 18 c5 6b 00 00 00 10 00
[ 3987.436600] end_request: I/O error, dev sda, sector 415591178
[ 3987.436627] ata1: EH complete
[ 3987.436663] XFS (sda6): metadata I/O error: block 0x181300 ("xfs_trans_read_buf_map") error 5 numblks 16
[ 3987.436674] XFS (sda6): xfs_imap_to_bp: xfs_trans_read_buf() returned error 5.
[ 4018.424628] ata1.00: exception Emask 0x0 SAct 0x8 SErr 0x0 action 0x0
[ 4018.424637] ata1.00: irq_stat 0x40000008
[ 4018.424643] ata1.00: failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED
[ 4018.424652] ata1.00: cmd 60/10:18:00:6b:c5/00:00:18:00:00/40 tag 3 ncq 8192 in
         res 41/40:00:0a:6b:c5/00:00:18:00:00/40 Emask 0x409 (media error) <F>
[ 4018.424657] ata1.00: status: { DRDY ERR }
[ 4018.424660] ata1.00: error: { UNC }
[ 4018.427241] ata1.00: configured for UDMA/133
[ 4018.427260] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Unhandled sense code
[ 4018.427264] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda]  
[ 4018.427268] Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[ 4018.427271] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda]  
[ 4018.427274] Sense Key : Medium Error [current] [descriptor]
[ 4018.427279] Descriptor sense data with sense descriptors (in hex):
[ 4018.427282]         72 03 11 04 00 00 00 0c 00 0a 80 00 00 00 00 00 
[ 4018.427295]         18 c5 6b 0a 
[ 4018.427301] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda]  
[ 4018.427305] Add. Sense: Unrecovered read error - auto reallocate failed
[ 4018.427309] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] CDB: 
[ 4018.427312] Read(10): 28 00 18 c5 6b 00 00 00 10 00
[ 4018.427324] end_request: I/O error, dev sda, sector 415591178
[ 4018.427356] ata1: EH complete
[ 4018.427392] XFS (sda6): metadata I/O error: block 0x181300 ("xfs_trans_read_buf_map") error 5 numblks 16
[ 4018.427404] XFS (sda6): xfs_imap_to_bp: xfs_trans_read_buf() returned error 5.
[ 4021.044847] ata1.00: exception Emask 0x0 SAct 0x10 SErr 0x0 action 0x0
[ 4021.044856] ata1.00: irq_stat 0x40000008
[ 4021.044863] ata1.00: failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED
[ 4021.044872] ata1.00: cmd 60/10:20:00:6b:c5/00:00:18:00:00/40 tag 4 ncq 8192 in
         res 41/40:00:0a:6b:c5/00:00:18:00:00/40 Emask 0x409 (media error) <F>
[ 4021.044877] ata1.00: status: { DRDY ERR }
[ 4021.044880] ata1.00: error: { UNC }
[ 4021.047478] ata1.00: configured for UDMA/133
[ 4021.047496] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Unhandled sense code
[ 4021.047501] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda]  
[ 4021.047504] Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[ 4021.047507] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda]  
[ 4021.047510] Sense Key : Medium Error [current] [descriptor]
[ 4021.047518] Descriptor sense data with sense descriptors (in hex):
[ 4021.047521]         72 03 11 04 00 00 00 0c 00 0a 80 00 00 00 00 00 
[ 4021.047534]         18 c5 6b 0a 
[ 4021.047541] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda]  
[ 4021.047545] Add. Sense: Unrecovered read error - auto reallocate failed
[ 4021.047549] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] CDB: 
[ 4021.047551] Read(10): 28 00 18 c5 6b 00 00 00 10 00
[ 4021.047563] end_request: I/O error, dev sda, sector 415591178
[ 4021.047591] ata1: EH complete
[ 4021.047627] XFS (sda6): metadata I/O error: block 0x181300 ("xfs_trans_read_buf_map") error 5 numblks 16
[ 4021.047643] XFS (sda6): xfs_imap_to_bp: xfs_trans_read_buf() returned error 5.
[ 4456.063628] ata1.00: exception Emask 0x0 SAct 0x4000 SErr 0x0 action 0x0
[ 4456.063637] ata1.00: irq_stat 0x40000008
[ 4456.063643] ata1.00: failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED
[ 4456.063656] ata1.00: cmd 60/10:70:00:6b:c5/00:00:18:00:00/40 tag 14 ncq 8192 in
         res 41/40:00:0a:6b:c5/00:00:18:00:00/40 Emask 0x409 (media error) <F>
[ 4456.063660] ata1.00: status: { DRDY ERR }
[ 4456.063664] ata1.00: error: { UNC }
[ 4456.066097] ata1.00: configured for UDMA/133
[ 4456.066114] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Unhandled sense code
[ 4456.066118] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda]  
[ 4456.066121] Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[ 4456.066124] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda]  
[ 4456.066127] Sense Key : Medium Error [current] [descriptor]
[ 4456.066133] Descriptor sense data with sense descriptors (in hex):
[ 4456.066135]         72 03 11 04 00 00 00 0c 00 0a 80 00 00 00 00 00 
[ 4456.066148]         18 c5 6b 0a 
[ 4456.066155] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda]  
[ 4456.066158] Add. Sense: Unrecovered read error - auto reallocate failed
[ 4456.066162] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] CDB: 
[ 4456.066165] Read(10): 28 00 18 c5 6b 00 00 00 10 00
[ 4456.066177] end_request: I/O error, dev sda, sector 415591178
[ 4456.066203] ata1: EH complete
[ 4456.066241] XFS (sda6): metadata I/O error: block 0x181300 ("xfs_trans_read_buf_map") error 5 numblks 16
[ 4456.066252] XFS (sda6): xfs_imap_to_bp: xfs_trans_read_buf() returned error 5.
[ 4458.620639] ata1.00: exception Emask 0x0 SAct 0x10000 SErr 0x0 action 0x0
[ 4458.620647] ata1.00: irq_stat 0x40000008
[ 4458.620653] ata1.00: failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED
[ 4458.620663] ata1.00: cmd 60/10:80:00:6b:c5/00:00:18:00:00/40 tag 16 ncq 8192 in
         res 41/40:00:0a:6b:c5/00:00:18:00:00/40 Emask 0x409 (media error) <F>
[ 4458.620667] ata1.00: status: { DRDY ERR }
[ 4458.620671] ata1.00: error: { UNC }
[ 4458.624534] ata1.00: configured for UDMA/133
[ 4458.624553] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Unhandled sense code
[ 4458.624557] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda]  
[ 4458.624560] Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[ 4458.624563] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda]  
[ 4458.624566] Sense Key : Medium Error [current] [descriptor]
[ 4458.624571] Descriptor sense data with sense descriptors (in hex):
[ 4458.624574]         72 03 11 04 00 00 00 0c 00 0a 80 00 00 00 00 00 
[ 4458.624587]         18 c5 6b 0a 
[ 4458.624594] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda]  
[ 4458.624597] Add. Sense: Unrecovered read error - auto reallocate failed
[ 4458.624601] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] CDB: 
[ 4458.624604] Read(10): 28 00 18 c5 6b 00 00 00 10 00
[ 4458.624616] end_request: I/O error, dev sda, sector 415591178
[ 4458.624644] ata1: EH complete
[ 4458.624682] XFS (sda6): metadata I/O error: block 0x181300 ("xfs_trans_read_buf_map") error 5 numblks 16
[ 4458.624694] XFS (sda6): xfs_imap_to_bp: xfs_trans_read_buf() returned error 5.
[ 4582.462663] ata1.00: exception Emask 0x0 SAct 0x2000 SErr 0x0 action 0x0
[ 4582.462671] ata1.00: irq_stat 0x40000008
[ 4582.462677] ata1.00: failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED
[ 4582.462695] ata1.00: cmd 60/10:68:00:6b:c5/00:00:18:00:00/40 tag 13 ncq 8192 in
         res 41/40:00:0a:6b:c5/00:00:18:00:00/40 Emask 0x409 (media error) <F>
[ 4582.462698] ata1.00: status: { DRDY ERR }
[ 4582.462701] ata1.00: error: { UNC }
[ 4582.465098] ata1.00: configured for UDMA/133
[ 4582.465111] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Unhandled sense code
[ 4582.465114] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda]  
[ 4582.465116] Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[ 4582.465119] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda]  
[ 4582.465121] Sense Key : Medium Error [current] [descriptor]
[ 4582.465125] Descriptor sense data with sense descriptors (in hex):
[ 4582.465127]         72 03 11 04 00 00 00 0c 00 0a 80 00 00 00 00 00 
[ 4582.465137]         18 c5 6b 0a 
[ 4582.465142] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda]  
[ 4582.465145] Add. Sense: Unrecovered read error - auto reallocate failed
[ 4582.465148] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] CDB: 
[ 4582.465150] Read(10): 28 00 18 c5 6b 00 00 00 10 00
[ 4582.465159] end_request: I/O error, dev sda, sector 415591178
[ 4582.465179] ata1: EH complete
[ 4582.465226] XFS (sda6): metadata I/O error: block 0x181300 ("xfs_trans_read_buf_map") error 5 numblks 16
[ 4582.465234] XFS (sda6): xfs_imap_to_bp: xfs_trans_read_buf() returned error 5.
[ 4758.761524] ata1.00: exception Emask 0x0 SAct 0x8000000 SErr 0x0 action 0x0
[ 4758.761532] ata1.00: irq_stat 0x40000008
[ 4758.761539] ata1.00: failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED
[ 4758.761549] ata1.00: cmd 60/10:d8:00:6b:c5/00:00:18:00:00/40 tag 27 ncq 8192 in
         res 41/40:00:0a:6b:c5/00:00:18:00:00/40 Emask 0x409 (media error) <F>
[ 4758.761553] ata1.00: status: { DRDY ERR }
[ 4758.761557] ata1.00: error: { UNC }
[ 4758.763977] ata1.00: configured for UDMA/133
[ 4758.763996] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Unhandled sense code
[ 4758.764000] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda]  
[ 4758.764042] Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[ 4758.764051] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda]  
[ 4758.764054] Sense Key : Medium Error [current] [descriptor]
[ 4758.764060] Descriptor sense data with sense descriptors (in hex):
[ 4758.764062]         72 03 11 04 00 00 00 0c 00 0a 80 00 00 00 00 00 
[ 4758.764076]         18 c5 6b 0a 
[ 4758.764082] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda]  
[ 4758.764086] Add. Sense: Unrecovered read error - auto reallocate failed
[ 4758.764090] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] CDB: 
[ 4758.764093] Read(10): 28 00 18 c5 6b 00 00 00 10 00
[ 4758.764105] end_request: I/O error, dev sda, sector 415591178
[ 4758.764133] ata1: EH complete
[ 4758.764381] XFS (sda6): metadata I/O error: block 0x181300 ("xfs_trans_read_buf_map") error 5 numblks 16
[ 4758.764391] XFS (sda6): xfs_imap_to_bp: xfs_trans_read_buf() returned error 5.
[ 4761.407790] ata1.00: exception Emask 0x0 SAct 0x8 SErr 0x0 action 0x0
[ 4761.407800] ata1.00: irq_stat 0x40000008
[ 4761.407806] ata1.00: failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED
[ 4761.407815] ata1.00: cmd 60/10:18:00:6b:c5/00:00:18:00:00/40 tag 3 ncq 8192 in
         res 41/40:00:0a:6b:c5/00:00:18:00:00/40 Emask 0x409 (media error) <F>
[ 4761.407820] ata1.00: status: { DRDY ERR }
[ 4761.407823] ata1.00: error: { UNC }
[ 4761.410215] ata1.00: configured for UDMA/133
[ 4761.410233] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Unhandled sense code
[ 4761.410237] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda]  
[ 4761.410240] Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[ 4761.410244] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda]  
[ 4761.410247] Sense Key : Medium Error [current] [descriptor]
[ 4761.410252] Descriptor sense data with sense descriptors (in hex):
[ 4761.410254]         72 03 11 04 00 00 00 0c 00 0a 80 00 00 00 00 00 
[ 4761.410268]         18 c5 6b 0a 
[ 4761.410274] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda]  
[ 4761.410278] Add. Sense: Unrecovered read error - auto reallocate failed
[ 4761.410282] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] CDB: 
[ 4761.410285] Read(10): 28 00 18 c5 6b 00 00 00 10 00
[ 4761.410297] end_request: I/O error, dev sda, sector 415591178
[ 4761.410322] ata1: EH complete
[ 4761.410370] XFS (sda6): metadata I/O error: block 0x181300 ("xfs_trans_read_buf_map") error 5 numblks 16
[ 4761.410383] XFS (sda6): xfs_imap_to_bp: xfs_trans_read_buf() returned error 5.
[ 4828.394331] ata1.00: exception Emask 0x0 SAct 0x4 SErr 0x0 action 0x0
[ 4828.394344] ata1.00: irq_stat 0x40000008
[ 4828.394350] ata1.00: failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED
[ 4828.394359] ata1.00: cmd 60/10:10:00:6b:c5/00:00:18:00:00/40 tag 2 ncq 8192 in
         res 41/40:00:0a:6b:c5/00:00:18:00:00/40 Emask 0x409 (media error) <F>
[ 4828.394364] ata1.00: status: { DRDY ERR }
[ 4828.394368] ata1.00: error: { UNC }
[ 4828.396963] ata1.00: configured for UDMA/133
[ 4828.396981] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Unhandled sense code
[ 4828.396986] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda]  
[ 4828.396989] Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[ 4828.396992] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda]  
[ 4828.396995] Sense Key : Medium Error [current] [descriptor]
[ 4828.397000] Descriptor sense data with sense descriptors (in hex):
[ 4828.397003]         72 03 11 04 00 00 00 0c 00 0a 80 00 00 00 00 00 
[ 4828.397016]         18 c5 6b 0a 
[ 4828.397023] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda]  
[ 4828.397026] Add. Sense: Unrecovered read error - auto reallocate failed
[ 4828.397030] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] CDB: 
[ 4828.397033] Read(10): 28 00 18 c5 6b 00 00 00 10 00
[ 4828.397045] end_request: I/O error, dev sda, sector 415591178
[ 4828.397075] ata1: EH complete
[ 4828.397125] XFS (sda6): metadata I/O error: block 0x181300 ("xfs_trans_read_buf_map") error 5 numblks 16
[ 4828.397135] XFS (sda6): xfs_imap_to_bp: xfs_trans_read_buf() returned error 5.
[ 4867.249634] ata1.00: exception Emask 0x0 SAct 0x40 SErr 0x0 action 0x0
[ 4867.249642] ata1.00: irq_stat 0x40000008
[ 4867.249651] ata1.00: failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED
[ 4867.249661] ata1.00: cmd 60/10:30:00:6b:c5/00:00:18:00:00/40 tag 6 ncq 8192 in
         res 41/40:00:0a:6b:c5/00:00:18:00:00/40 Emask 0x409 (media error) <F>
[ 4867.249666] ata1.00: status: { DRDY ERR }
[ 4867.249669] ata1.00: error: { UNC }
[ 4867.252373] ata1.00: configured for UDMA/133
[ 4867.252397] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Unhandled sense code
[ 4867.252401] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda]  
[ 4867.252406] Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[ 4867.252410] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda]  
[ 4867.252413] Sense Key : Medium Error [current] [descriptor]
[ 4867.252418] Descriptor sense data with sense descriptors (in hex):
[ 4867.252421]         72 03 11 04 00 00 00 0c 00 0a 80 00 00 00 00 00 
[ 4867.252434]         18 c5 6b 0a 
[ 4867.252441] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda]  
[ 4867.252444] Add. Sense: Unrecovered read error - auto reallocate failed
[ 4867.252448] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] CDB: 
[ 4867.252451] Read(10): 28 00 18 c5 6b 00 00 00 10 00
[ 4867.252464] end_request: I/O error, dev sda, sector 415591178
[ 4867.252490] ata1: EH complete
[ 4867.252528] XFS (sda6): metadata I/O error: block 0x181300 ("xfs_trans_read_buf_map") error 5 numblks 16
[ 4867.252537] XFS (sda6): xfs_imap_to_bp: xfs_trans_read_buf() returned error 5.
[ 4906.471548] ata1.00: exception Emask 0x0 SAct 0x20000000 SErr 0x0 action 0x0
[ 4906.471556] ata1.00: irq_stat 0x40000008
[ 4906.471563] ata1.00: failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED
[ 4906.471572] ata1.00: cmd 60/10:e8:00:6b:c5/00:00:18:00:00/40 tag 29 ncq 8192 in
         res 41/40:00:0a:6b:c5/00:00:18:00:00/40 Emask 0x409 (media error) <F>
[ 4906.471577] ata1.00: status: { DRDY ERR }
[ 4906.471580] ata1.00: error: { UNC }
[ 4906.474090] ata1.00: configured for UDMA/133
[ 4906.474112] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Unhandled sense code
[ 4906.474116] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda]  
[ 4906.474119] Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[ 4906.474123] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda]  
[ 4906.474126] Sense Key : Medium Error [current] [descriptor]
[ 4906.474134] Descriptor sense data with sense descriptors (in hex):
[ 4906.474137]         72 03 11 04 00 00 00 0c 00 0a 80 00 00 00 00 00 
[ 4906.474150]         18 c5 6b 0a 
[ 4906.474157] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda]  
[ 4906.474161] Add. Sense: Unrecovered read error - auto reallocate failed
[ 4906.474165] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] CDB: 
[ 4906.474167] Read(10): 28 00 18 c5 6b 00 00 00 10 00
[ 4906.474179] end_request: I/O error, dev sda, sector 415591178
[ 4906.474207] ata1: EH complete
[ 4906.474252] XFS (sda6): metadata I/O error: block 0x181300 ("xfs_trans_read_buf_map") error 5 numblks 16
[ 4906.474261] XFS (sda6): xfs_imap_to_bp: xfs_trans_read_buf() returned error 5.
[ 4970.648872] ata1.00: exception Emask 0x0 SAct 0x80000 SErr 0x0 action 0x0
[ 4970.648880] ata1.00: irq_stat 0x40000008
[ 4970.648887] ata1.00: failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED
[ 4970.648896] ata1.00: cmd 60/10:98:00:6b:c5/00:00:18:00:00/40 tag 19 ncq 8192 in
         res 41/40:00:0a:6b:c5/00:00:18:00:00/40 Emask 0x409 (media error) <F>
[ 4970.648901] ata1.00: status: { DRDY ERR }
[ 4970.648904] ata1.00: error: { UNC }
[ 4970.651990] ata1.00: configured for UDMA/133
[ 4970.652055] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Unhandled sense code
[ 4970.652066] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda]  
[ 4970.652071] Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[ 4970.652075] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda]  
[ 4970.652078] Sense Key : Medium Error [current] [descriptor]
[ 4970.652083] Descriptor sense data with sense descriptors (in hex):
[ 4970.652086]         72 03 11 04 00 00 00 0c 00 0a 80 00 00 00 00 00 
[ 4970.652100]         18 c5 6b 0a 
[ 4970.652107] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda]  
[ 4970.652110] Add. Sense: Unrecovered read error - auto reallocate failed
[ 4970.652114] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] CDB: 
[ 4970.652117] Read(10): 28 00 18 c5 6b 00 00 00 10 00
[ 4970.652129] end_request: I/O error, dev sda, sector 415591178
[ 4970.652158] ata1: EH complete
[ 4970.652390] XFS (sda6): metadata I/O error: block 0x181300 ("xfs_trans_read_buf_map") error 5 numblks 16
[ 4970.652399] XFS (sda6): xfs_imap_to_bp: xfs_trans_read_buf() returned error 5.
[ 4973.216988] ata1.00: exception Emask 0x0 SAct 0x800000 SErr 0x0 action 0x0
[ 4973.216996] ata1.00: irq_stat 0x40000008
[ 4973.217002] ata1.00: failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED
[ 4973.217012] ata1.00: cmd 60/10:b8:00:6b:c5/00:00:18:00:00/40 tag 23 ncq 8192 in
         res 41/40:00:0a:6b:c5/00:00:18:00:00/40 Emask 0x409 (media error) <F>
[ 4973.217017] ata1.00: status: { DRDY ERR }
[ 4973.217020] ata1.00: error: { UNC }
[ 4973.221198] ata1.00: configured for UDMA/133
[ 4973.221216] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Unhandled sense code
[ 4973.221221] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda]  
[ 4973.221224] Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[ 4973.221227] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda]  
[ 4973.221230] Sense Key : Medium Error [current] [descriptor]
[ 4973.221235] Descriptor sense data with sense descriptors (in hex):
[ 4973.221238]         72 03 11 04 00 00 00 0c 00 0a 80 00 00 00 00 00 
[ 4973.221251]         18 c5 6b 0a 
[ 4973.221257] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda]  
[ 4973.221261] Add. Sense: Unrecovered read error - auto reallocate failed
[ 4973.221265] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] CDB: 
[ 4973.221267] Read(10): 28 00 18 c5 6b 00 00 00 10 00
[ 4973.221279] end_request: I/O error, dev sda, sector 415591178
[ 4973.221307] ata1: EH complete
[ 4973.221359] XFS (sda6): metadata I/O error: block 0x181300 ("xfs_trans_read_buf_map") error 5 numblks 16
[ 4973.221375] XFS (sda6): xfs_imap_to_bp: xfs_trans_read_buf()
```

And for `smartctl -A` :

```
bash: smartctl: command not found
```

`

Comment: Try `sudo smartctl -A /dev/sda`, if that's how you normally run things as root.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've experienced (at least) a bad block on your disk. Unfortunately, it hit an XFS data structure, so you've lost some filesystem metadata. I hope you have backups.

### Check smartctl

Hopefully you have `smartctl` installed (it needs to run as root, e.g., via `sudo`). If installed, it should give output like this:

```
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
  1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate     0x000f   103   098   006    Pre-fail  Always       -       212688305
  3 Spin_Up_Time            0x0003   094   094   000    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  4 Start_Stop_Count        0x0032   100   100   020    Old_age   Always       -       76
  5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   0x0033   002   002   036    Pre-fail  Always   FAILING_NOW 4015
  7 Seek_Error_Rate         0x000f   084   060   030    Pre-fail  Always       -       291678490
  9 Power_On_Hours          0x0032   052   052   000    Old_age   Always       -       42540
 10 Spin_Retry_Count        0x0013   100   100   097    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       0x0032   100   100   020    Old_age   Always       -       39
183 Runtime_Bad_Block       0x0032   098   098   000    Old_age   Always       -       2
184 End-to-End_Error        0x0032   100   100   099    Old_age   Always       -       0
187 Reported_Uncorrect      0x0032   018   018   000    Old_age   Always       -       82
188 Command_Timeout         0x0032   100   097   000    Old_age   Always       -       25770393781
189 High_Fly_Writes         0x003a   084   084   000    Old_age   Always       -       16
190 Airflow_Temperature_Cel 0x0022   061   061   045    Old_age   Always       -       39 (Min/Max 38/39)
194 Temperature_Celsius     0x0022   039   040   000    Old_age   Always       -       39 (0 16 0 0 0)
195 Hardware_ECC_Recovered  0x001a   034   013   000    Old_age   Always       -       212688305
197 Current_Pending_Sector  0x0012   100   099   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
198 Offline_Uncorrectable   0x0010   100   099   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0
199 UDMA_CRC_Error_Count    0x003e   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
240 Head_Flying_Hours       0x0000   100   253   000    Old_age   Offline      -       42617 (160 246 0)
241 Total_LBAs_Written      0x0000   100   253   000    Old_age   Offline      -       3791056483
242 Total_LBAs_Read         0x0000   100   253   000    Old_age   Offline      -       1003117143
```

The exact attributes shown vary from disk to disk, but most all of them have a 197 and/or 198 telling you how many un-repaired bad sectors the disk knows about. In the above output, you can see #5 is `FAILING_NOW`, and it's type is `Pre-fail`. That means the disk firmware expects the disk to fail within 24 hours. If you have any failed attributes, especially pre-fail ones, I'd replace the disk (and if its still under warranty, you should be able to RMA it).

### If you do not have smartctl

If you don't have smartctl, now is **not** the time to install it.

### Critical next step

If you have any important files on the machine disk—especially ones that haven't already been backed up—attempt to copy them to a different disk, USB flash drive, network share, etc. Your filesystem has been damaged, and it's possible this is your last chance to do so easily.

### Use a live system to run smartctl, xfs_repair

If you don't have `smartctl` installed, you can reboot (after copying off important data!) into a live system (from CD, USB stick, etc.) and run smartctl from there. You can also use `xfs_repair` from the live system to attempt filesystem repair. (Please read the manpage for `xfs_repair` first; I confess to not having much experience with XFS).

Note that disks made in the last decade or two have spare sectors and will use on of them to replace the bad sector the next time it's written to. `smartctl -A` will normally have attributes showing how many times this has been done.

### After filesystem repair

If there were important files you couldn't grab before, you can now try again.

Depending on bad the damage was (how many files you lost, and which ones), you'll need to either re-install a few packages (using `dpkg -i` or `apt-get install --reinstall`) or, if it was bad, re-install the OS.

Of course, if you have a recent full-system backup, probably easiest to restore from backup.

### How to prevent this in the future

Using two disks (in a mdraid RAID1 mirror) allows the kernel to deal with bad blocks by reading the sector from the other disk. It then writes the correct data back, allowing the disk to use a spare sector. You can also run RAID1 between two partitions on the same disk, which will half your available space but protect against bad sectors (but not against the disk failing entirely).

Some filesystems (e.g., btrfs with "duplicate" mode) can keep two copies of their metadata or your data, also protecting against bad sectors.

Answer (score -1):

edit file /var/lib/dpkg/status

search any entry with liba52-0.7.4 and just deleted

i hope this solv your problem

please forgive my english it´s not my native language